# why this would result in long integer overflow

Tags: c#, integer

I checked the document that `long`= `int64` has range more than 900,000,000,000,000

Here is my code:

```
int r = 99;
long test1 = r*r*r*r*r;
```

at runtime it gives me 919,965,907 instead of the correct 9,509,900,499.

another test

```
long test2 = 99*99*99*99*99;
```

It refuses to compile, saying integer overflow.

But if i do this

```
long test3 = 10100200300;
```

This works fine.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem is that the literal "99" is being treated as an int.  If you add "L" it will treat it as a long.  To fix your compilation problem:

```
long test2 = 99L * 99L * 99L * 99L * 99L;
```

And to fix the "incorrect result" caused by integer overflow:

```
long r = 99;
long test1 = r * r * r * r * r;
```

The key point is that the expression to the right of the "=" is evaluated *before* the assignment to `long r` is done.

There are other literal suffixes you might be interested in:

```
Type    Suffix    Example
uint    U or u    100U
long    L or l    100L
ulong   UL or ul  100UL
float   F or f    123.45F
decimal M or m    123.45M
```

@m.edmonson, regarding your question about why it comes out to 919965907.  What's happening, is that the value is "wrapping" around int.MaxValue.  You can see this with a little test program:

```
int i = 99; // 99
i *= 99;    // 9801
i *= 99;    // 970299
i *= 99;    // 96059601
i *= 99;    // 919965907        should be 9509900499 but comes out to 919965907
            //                      which is (9509900499 % int.MaxValue)

long k = 9509900499 % int.MaxValue;
```

What is meant by "wrapping around"?  When you exceed `int.MaxValue` by 1, the value "goes back" to `int.MinValue`.

```
int j = int.MaxValue;
j++;

bool isNowMinValue = (j == int.MinValue);   // true, the value has "wrapped around"
```

This is a bit simplistic; if you search for "integer overflow" you will get a better explanation.  It's worth understanding how integers (and other numeric types) are represented with 32 bits:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: Excellent answer - can you explain why he gets a different result between long and integer multiplication?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by wrapping?  And what thats got to do with modulus % ?

Comment: I believe you only need one `99L`, the rest will upcast.

Comment: s/upcast/undergo integral promotion/

Comment: Int values are not wrapped around "int.MaxValue" and formula "9509900499 % int.MaxValue" is not correct. Correct formula is: "(9509900499 + int.MaxValue + 1) % ((long)int.MaxValue - int.MinValue + 1) - int.MaxValue - 1"

Answer (score 5):

It's using integer multiplication :

```
long r = 99;
long test1 = r*r*r*r*r;
```

Answer (score 4):

As the other have said, but:

```
long test2 = 99L * 99 * 99 * 99 * 99;
```

This will give you the correct result with less `L` around :-)

This happens because the first 99L is a `long`, so all the multiplications are done in the `long` "field" and all the other integers are upcasted to `long` before the multiplication (clearly the multiplication is always between 2 numbers and it's from left to right, so it's like (((99L * 99) * 99) * 99) * 99 and each "partial" result is a long and causes the next operand to be converted to long.)

Answer (score 3):

Your second test fails because each 99 is an integer; replace it with the following and it compiles.

```
long test2 = 99L * 99L * 99L * 99L * 99L;
```

See the [MSDN Long Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is looking at 99 as integers, even though the final result will be long.

This will work.

```
long test2 = 99L*99L*99L*99L*99L;
```